# Upload and resize image issues

Tags: php

What i'm trying to do is upload and resize images to my web server, a fairly simple process which i never thought i would be having issues with, my site images folder structure:

```
site.com/services/fs/
site.com/services/th/
```

The above structure is how my folders are inside my site files, "fullsize" and "thumbnail" i can upload the full size image with no issues but i'm having trouble saving the thumbnail in the thumbnail folder:

**Upload code:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitNewService'])) {

    // TRY/CATCH //
    try {

        // IMAGE UPLOAD / RESIZE //
        $original         = $_FILES['service_image']['name'];
        $maxwidth         = '500';
        $maxheight        = '500';
        $random_number    = rand(0, 999999);
        $allowed_image_types = [
            'image/gif',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/x-png',
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/bmp'
        ];  
        $imageRestrictions = @getimagesize($_FILES['service_image']['tmp_name']);
        $renamedImage      = "service-" . $random_number . '.' . substr($_FILES['service_image']['name'], strtolower(strlen($_FILES['service_image']['name'])) - 3, 3);
        if (($imageRestrictions[0] >= $maxwidth) || ($imageRestrictions[1] >= $maxheight)) {
            stderr(sprintf('Sorry that <b>image</b> is bigger than <b>%s</b>x<b>%s</b>!', $maxwidth, $maxheight));
        }

        if (!empty($_FILES['service_image']['name'])) {
            if (!in_array($_FILES['service_image']['type'], $allowed_image_types)) {
                stderr('The <b>uploaded</b> image does not appear to be a valid file!');
            }
            $uploadpath = '../services/fs/' . $renamedImage;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['service_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath);
        }

        $imgResized = resize_image($uploadpath, $renamedImage);
        // IMAGE UPLOAD / RESIZE //

        DB::getInstance()->insert(
            'services',
        [
            'service_user_id' => $globId,
            'service_name' => $_POST['service_name'],
            'service_body' => nl2br($_POST['service_body']),
            'service_cost' => $_POST['service_cost'],
            'service_category' => $_POST['service_category'],
            'service_image' => $renamedImage,
            'service_thumb_image' => $imgResized,
            'service_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);

        stdmsg("Your service [ <b>{$_POST['service_name']}</b> ] has been added successfully!");        

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        stderr($e->getMessage());
    }

}

?>
```

**Resize function:**

```
<?php

function resize_image($uploadDirectory, $newFileName) {
    $original_image   = $uploadDirectory;
    $ext              = substr($original_image, strrpos($original_image, '.') + 1);
    $canvas_width     = 480;
    $canvas_height    = 250;
    $canvas           = imagecreatetruecolor($canvas_width, $canvas_height);
    $white_background = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $white_background);
    list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($uploadDirectory);

    $ratio = $image_width / $image_height;

    if ($ratio > 1) {
        $new_image_width  = 65;
        $new_image_height = 65 / $ratio;
    } else {
        $new_image_width  = (float) 65 * $ratio;
        $new_image_height = 65;
    }

    if ($ext == "jpg") {
        $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_image);
    } 

    if ($ext == "gif") {
        $original_image = imagecreatefromgif($original_image);
    } 

    imagecopyresampled($canvas, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_image_width, $new_image_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $new_thumbnail_name = "thumb-$newFileName";

    if ($ext == "jpg") {
        imagejpeg($canvas, "../services/th/{$new_thumbnail_name}", 100);
        return $new_thumbnail_name;
    } 

    if ($ext == "gif") {
        imagegif($canvas, "../services/th/{$new_thumbnail_name}", 100);
        return $new_thumbnail_name;
    } 

    imagedestroy($original_image);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
}

?>
```

The resize code i took from another project which worked great a few years ago, i just cannot get the thumbnail to save in the thumbnail folder, is there something small i have missed, the file paths look fine to me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the code snippets you've posted are in different files? Are they located in the same folder?

Comment: Hi Magnus, the resize function is is in: site.com/includes/functions.php and the upload code is in: site.com/add-new-service.php

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path to the upload folder instead of a relative path? You should also do some debugging and see where your resize code fails. Check what the variables contain in different steps and what the different functions actually return.

Comment: Thank you Magnus, it seems there is no need for "../" to be appended, i don't understand why as it is up a directory, but none the less :)

Comment: Relative paths are relative from the top file that includes the files. It can easily be a bit messy using relative paths if you include files that include files etc. It's always recommended to use absolute paths using the magic constant `__DIR__`. That constant will return the absolute path to the file it's written in.

Comment: Ah thank you very much Magnus :)